# Conditional row ranking in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by

In a test consisting of Maths and Science papers the following is the selection rule:

- Everyone should attempt either one or both of Maths and Science.
- Those who attempt for Maths will be selected based on time taken in solving Maths only.
- Those who don't attempt for Maths will be selected based on time taken in solving Science.

Not attempted papers is recorded as Time = 0, which should not be counted for selection.

```
--------------------------
 Student | Subject | Time
--------------------------
 1       | S       | 24
 2       | S       | 60
 1       | M       | 65
 2       | M       | 0
 3       | S       | 0
 3       | M       | 0
--------------------------
```

Here the selected value should be `2  -  S  -  60`, as he took minimum time for the qualifying attempt (Science) as he did not attempt Maths.

How to do this in a *single* MySQL Query?

I cannot use the following as they fail in one or the other case:

```
SELECT
    student_id, subject_id, time_taken
FROM test_stats
WHERE
    time_taken > 0
ORDER BY
    time_taken ASC,
    subject_id ASC
LIMIT 0, 1;
```

OR

```
SELECT
    student_id, subject_id, time_taken
FROM test_stats
WHERE
    time_taken > 0
ORDER BY
    subject_id ASC,
    time_taken ASC,
LIMIT 0, 1;
```

Not even `GROUP BY` is helpful, as we cannot set `ORDER BY` within group sets.

Let me know if I need to elaborate on anything further.

Comment: post how your output should be?

Comment: @ArunKrish I already said it in the question ... the selected value should be `2  -  S  -  60`,...

Comment: what is the condition to select.. like subject = 's' ...?

Comment: Read the top 3 points. ONE **Minimum time taker** would be selected. Those who attempt for Maths (M) will be scored based on time taken in Maths only. Those who don't attempt for Maths will be scored based on time taken in solving Science (S). In above example Student 2 would be selected based on his Science score as.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT student_id, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(subject_id ORDER BY subject_id),',',1) as subject, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(time_taken ORDER BY subject_id),',',1) as time_take
FROM test_stats
WHERE time_taken != 0 
GROUP BY student_id 
ORDER BY time_take ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

You have mentioned the subject preference should be Maths(M),Based on that

1)`GROUP_CONCAT(subject_id ORDER BY subject_id)` will be anyone of the following.
 (Note: I have added condition in WHERE clause like time_taken!=0, So you won't get the subjects with time_taken 0 here)

> a)M, S (when student attended both subjects)
>
> b)M (When student attended Maths alone)
>
> c)S (When student attended Science alone)

2) And SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(subject_id ORDER BY subject_id),',',1) will give you

> a)M (when student attended both subjects)
>
> b)M (When student attended Maths alone)
>
> c)S (When student attended Science alone)

The same conditions suits for time_taken also.

Comment: The criteria is NOT the SUM, rather it is the time taken for the qualifying subject only. viz either maths (if attempted) or science (all other cases)...

Comment: Why `GROUP_CONCAT` and `SUBSTRING_INDEX` and you did not check for `M` or `S`. How and why your code should work? Please explain!

Comment: I have added the explanation. Please check it. Let me know if you need any other explanation